# Explain some parameters of IntlDateFormatter's constructor

Tags: php, datetime, internationalization, date-format

I am trying to change the way we format dates in our application (we used `strftime`, `strtotime`, etc.) to use the more up to date `IntlDateFormatter`. I [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php), but I can't really understand all the constructor's parameters. Can someone explain it to me ? This is how I see things now :

- `locale` : I get this one : locale used to output month names, day names, etc.
- `datetype` : I really don't understand what it's used for. Is it the input format ? Why is it so limited to a few constants ? Doc says *"Date type to use"* What do they mean by date type ?
- `timetype` : Same for this one, what is it ? Why is it so limited to a few constants ? Doc says *"Time type to use"*
- `timezone` : I get it, timezone to used
- `calendar` : I get this one : type of calendar, Gregorian most of the time
- `pattern` : Actual pattern I want my date to be formatted

So, it's the `datetype` and `timetype` that I don't really understand what it's used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those flags specify how much information to output about the date/time.  The [documentation about the constants used](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants) give a little more insight than what you linked in your question.

So basically if `datetype` is set to `IntlDateFormatter::LONG` the output should be `January 12, 1952`, or if it was set to `IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM` than the output should be `Jan 12, 1952`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is it. If I set `datetype` to `IntlDateFormatter::SHORT`, but my pattern to `cccc MMMM d y` it outputs : Sunday January 26 2014 so it does not seems to have an impact on the output.

Comment: @MaxiWheat The pattern will override the the `datetype` and `timetype` settings.  If you remove your pattern it will work as expected.  If your pattern is how you would like to format your timestamp, then simply don't use the `datetype` and `timetype` settings.

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't obvious that these parameters were "default formatting" if no pattern was specified.

Comment: @MaxiWheat I know exactly how you feel.  There has been more than one time where I found myself tinkering with code to find out how PHP was going to do something.  Glad that helped you out.